# JavaFX Charting - CategoryAixis Resize Issue

Tags: charts, javafx-8

I have a user-resizable chart. When the chart gets smaller the CategoryAxis rotates and you can no longer see most of the category labels. Here is a gif showing the problem:

[image: Example of Issue]

Is there any way to stop the labels from rotating?

I know I can add a listener to the rotation property and rotate it back to 0 if the rotation changes. However, when I do that it doesn't prevent the spacing from adjusting, so the labels just get cut off (you only see the last few characters of the label).

Here is the code for the included gif, you'll see the problem as you resize the window:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HorizontalBarExample extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)  {
        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        CategoryAxis yAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        BarChart<Number, String> bc = new BarChart<Number, String>(xAxis, yAxis);
        bc.setBarGap(0d);
        bc.setCategoryGap(0);

        xAxis.setTickLabelRotation(90);
        yAxis.tickLabelRotationProperty().set(0d);

        XYChart.Series<Number, String> series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
        series1.setName("example");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, String>(Math.random() * 5000, "long data label number" + i));

        bc.getData().add(series1);

        Scene scene = new Scene(bc, 800, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would say, it's a bug: whatever the category axis should do if the space gets to small to show all labels horizontally, rotation is not one of the viable options (leaving out every n'th might - or not - be, or not showing any until the mouse hovers over the category and then show only that one)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is not easily fixable (IMO).

*What's going on*

The CategoryAxis code for Java 8u60 internally maintains a private `effectiveTickLabelRotation` member.  This member can at times, due to the internal implementation, override whatever value you set for the publicly available `tickLabelRotationProperty`.  So you don't really have much control over the functionality.

*Various (failed) attempts to fix it using public API*

One way that it overrides is when the the category axis is set to autoRanging, so you can set autoRanging to false and also manually set the categories using the `CategoryAxis::setCategory` method.  This kind of fixes the issue because then the effectiveRotation is not used when the graph gets small, it respects the rotation you want and the text stays vertical.

However, even with switching auto ranging off and manually setting categories, there are other quirks in the implementation which prevent a reasonable result.  The internal layout algorithm for the CategoryAxis still thinks that the category labels have been rotated, so it does not allocate enough space for the labels when the chart gets smaller.  The CategoryAxis class is final so the layout logic can't be overridden in a subclass.  A quick hack would be set a minimum width for the axis, `yAxis.setMinWidth(200);`.  Unfortunately the CategoryAxis layout algorithm does not respect the min width setting either.

*Options to get this functionality*

In short, it's all kind of broken ... you either:

1. Accept the default behavior as is, OR
2. You [log a bug](http://bugreport.java.com) requesting a fix, OR
3. You copy the CategoryAxis code to a new class, e.g. HorizontallyLabelledCategoryAxis, make some modifications to allow the layout algorithm to work as you wish and use that new class in place of the original CategoryAxis.

Option 3 is a bit tricky, but doable.

*Suggested Work-around*

All that said, the approach (e.g. work-around) I'd recommend, if it is acceptable for your UI, is simply not to let the chart get small enough that its layout screws up.

```
VBox chartHolder = new VBox(bc);
VBox.setVgrow(bc, Priority.ALWAYS);
bc.setMinHeight(300);
Scene scene = new Scene(chartHolder, 800, 600);
```